# para que sirve el signo de interrogacion antes de una variable

Tags: html, html5, url

Buenas disculpen una pregunta estoy iniciando en php y un compañero me pregunto para que sirve el signo de interrogacion antes de una variable ya que el lo esta usando en esta parte

< a href=**"?cargar'='crear"**>Registrar < /a>

yo digo que es para pasar variables por url pero no estoy seguro si es eso o que es lo que hace esa parte de codigo

Comment: las comillas que tienes son un poco raras. No debería haber nada en el =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es correcto, eso es a lo que se le llama "URL Query string".

En los comienzos de la web las direcciones de las páginas contenían la estructura jerárquica de los directorios del sitio. Por ejemplo:

www.sitiodeejemplo.net/paginaprincipal/paginasecundaria/contenido.html

Estos sitios eran estáticos: a menos que el administrador modifique las páginas siempre mostrarían el mismo contenido a los visitantes.

Más tarde aparecieron los sitios dinámicos. En este caso, el servidor crea automáticamente la página cuando el navegante la solicita. Para ello se vale de una serie de parámetros o datos que se incluyen en la URL. Estos normalmente están compuestos por un nombre y un valor separados por el signo igual. Un ejemplo de dirección dinámica sería:

www.sitiodeejemplo.net/pagina.php?nombredevalor1=valor1&nombredevalor2=valor2

El ?"" se utiliza para dividir el URL del Query string. El Query string es básicamente una lista de variables y sus valores.

Para ser mas preciso, en la URL que estes, ira pero con los parametros:

- cargar, que su valor es 'crear'

```html
< a href="?cargar'='crear">Registrar < /a>
```

quedando por ejemplo como resultado 
[www.sitiodeejemplo.net/pagina.php?cargar=crear](http://www.sitiodeejemplo.net/pagina.php?cargar=crear)

Answer (score 3):

Sí, es para pasar variables de una página a otra a través de la URL. Aunque en tu caso concreto, sería para pasar variables a la misma página en la que te encuentras (porque no se especifica ninguna en el enlace).

Entonces en PHP podrás leer la variable a través del `$_GET`:

```
$miVar = $_GET["cargar"];
```

(idealmente tendrías que comprobar que el parámetro existe y que no está vacío, etc, pero esto es sólo un ejemplo)